# Define Selected Item in Kendo ComboBox

Tags: kendo-ui

When I set the selected item in the Kendo ComboBox, it will display the Value and not the Text of the Item.

```
 foreach (var v in Model.Projects)
  {
    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Value = v.Project_Id;
    item.Text = v.Description;

    if (v.Project_Id.Equals(Model.Project_Id))
    {
      item.Selected = true;
    }
    list.Add(item);
  }

            }

            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .Name("mycombo")
              .BindTo(list)
              .Enable(true)
              .AutoBind(false)

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to set the auto bind to true, so the text would be loaded immediately and not only when the user clicked the combo box.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .Name("mycombo")
              .BindTo(list)
              .Enable(true)
              .AutoBind(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your ComboBox wrapper with the **DataTextField** and **DataValueField** to tell it specifically what fields to use.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .Name("mycombo")
              .BindTo(list)
              .Enable(true)
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .AutoBind(false))
```

Comment: It didn't revolved the issue.
If I put .DataTextField("Value") the initial field has the value and the items have the value.
But if I put .DataTextField("Text") then the initial field has the value and the items have the text.

Comment: Are you using both **.DataTextField("Text")** and **.DataValueField("Value")**? From your comment it looks like you are not using the .DataValueField.

Comment: Solved it.
Just needed to set the auto bind to true.
This way the text would be loaded immediately and not only when the user clicked the combo box.